# React Change a label button on who is on a map

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, button, label

I have a problem. Here is my code :

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import CurrentUserContext from "../contexts/userContext";
import userAPI from "../services/userAPI";

export default function DisplayCameras() {
  const [cameras, setCameras] = useState([]);
  const [cool, setCool] = useState([]);
  const [erreur, setErreur] = useState("");
  const { user } = useContext(CurrentUserContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let arr = [];

  const getCameras = () => {
    userAPI.get("/api/cameras").then((response) => {
      setCameras(response.data[0]);
    });
  };

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const deleteCamera = (id) => {
    if (user) {
      userAPI
        .delete(`/api/cameras/${id}`)
        .then(() => {
          setCameras(
            cameras.filter((data) => {
              return data.id !== id;
            })
          );
          toast.success("Camera supprimé avec succes");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        });
    } else toast.warning("Vous n'êtes pas connecté !");
  };

  const addCool = (cooler) => {
    setErreur("");
    console.warn("add Cooler");
    arr.push(cooler);
    console.warn("arr:", arr);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    arr = [];
    console.warn("arr reset:", arr);
    setCool([]);
    setErreur("");
  };

  const total = () => {
    if (arr.length === 1) {
      console.warn("ATTENTION 1 SEULE VALEUR AJOUTE");
      setErreur("ATTENTION, 1 SEULE VALEUR AJOUTE");
    }
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      console.warn("ATTENTION PAS DE VALEUR AJOUTE");
      setErreur("ATTENTION, PAS DE VALEUR AJOUTE");
    } else {
      const calcul = arr.reduce((curr, acc) => {
        return curr + acc;
      });
      setCool(calcul);
      console.warn("total: ", calcul);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCameras();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" onClick={() => navigate("create-camera")}>
          Créer une nouvelle camera
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {cameras.map((data) => (
          <div key={data.id}>
            <p>{data.brand}</p>
            <p>{data.cooler}</p>
            <p>{data.cadence}</p>
            <label htmlFor="cooler">cooler</label>

            <button
              type="button"
              value="cooler"
              onClick={() => addCool(data.cooler)}
            >
              toto
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={total}>
        Total
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={reset}>
        Reset
      </button>
      <h2>{cool}</h2>
      <p>{erreur}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to change my button label (with the value cooler) for each individual map but after some test, i made a state who change all my buttons label, not just one :/

I tried a lot of things with no luck... I heard i have to create a state for each button ??

Can someone help me plz ?

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what actually you want to change here ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then unfortunately React will have to rerender all of the JSX you create in the `map` method.

This is because you are not changing one element in your array (well, you *are* but hear me out), you are changing *the whole array* (its reference). Even if 99 out of 100 elements are the same, for React it is a different array, thus a complete rerender is necessary.

You can however improve your code by extracting this part:

```
      <div key={data.id}>
        <p>{data.brand}</p>
        <p>{data.cooler}</p>
        <p>{data.cadence}</p>
        <label htmlFor="cooler">cooler</label>

        <button
          type="button"
          value="cooler"
          onClick={() => addCool(data.cooler)}
        >
          toto
        </button>
      </div>
```

into a separate component, say `Camera`.

```
const Camera = memo(({ brand, cooler, cadence, onAddCool }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{brand}</p>
      <p>{cooler}</p>
      <p>{cadence}</p>
      <label htmlFor="cooler">cooler</label>

      <button
        type="button"
        value="cooler"
        onClick={() => onAddCool(cooler)}
      >
        toto
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Camera;
```

and use it in your map method:

```
    {cameras.map((data) => (
      <Camera {...data} onAddCool={addCool} key={data.id} />
    )}
```

Now, thanks to `memo()` wrapping your `Camera` component, it will be rerendered only if any of its props has changed. This means, even if your `cameras` array is completely new array with only 1 changed element, only a single Camera component (correlated with one changed element inside the array) will be rerendered.